# How to return differet value from specified in the method?

Tags: java

The method should return the value of type Animal. In case something goes wrong, and i want to indicate that there is an error, what is the right technique?
In case i don't want to raise an error. What can i return instead of type Animal?

```
public static Animal make_child(Animal a, Animal b) {
   // Create a child if both animals of different male
   Animal c;
   if (a.male == b.male) {
      return null;
   }
   c = new Animal(...);
}
```

Comment: Can you not just raise an exception?

Comment: Friend has a beginner course. They didn't learn exceptions yet. 
Other ways to do that?
According to exercise, it's logical to return null. If they can't make a child.
In exercise it's not specified to return one of the parent's Classes. 
Neither they learn exceptions. That's why I'm asking. 
Is there a way to return an Empty class instance? The type would match, but it wouldn't have anything inside?

Comment: Your code already returns null to signal something, so that's out.  You could insert a class into the 'animal' inheritance branch that included an error flag/message for the caller to check or....learn about exceptions:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using exception handling for this type of issue, here is a link https://www.javatpoint.com/exception-handling-in-java, but if you don't want to use it, you can just return null as you did in your exception above. When you will call the method and the answer will be null, you will be able to make the difference between the right Animal and the wrong one. As example:

```
//do you really want this method static?
    public static Animal make_child(Animal a, Animal b) {
         // Create a child if both animals of different male
           Animal c;
           if (a.male == b.male) {
              return null;
           }
           c = new Animal(...);
        }
     public static void isNewbornBoyOrGirl(Animal a, Animal b) {
        Animal newborn = make_child(a,b);
        if(newborn == null)
        {
          System.out.println("An error has occured!");
          return;
//if the newborn is null, a print will be displayed and afterward it will exit the current method 
        }
        // do stuff with newborn as it is not null after calling the method above
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If something goes wrong you should throw an exception.

```java
throw new Exception("Something went wrong.")
```

I would recommend you to get familiar with exception handling here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-exceptions

Comment: I wasn't clear in my question. If i don't want to raise an error, is there a technique to return null, or empty object ? From a method that should return Animal?

Comment: If neither an exception, nor `null` is an option, you could instantiate and return a new Animal object, like this: `return new Animal()` (assuming the constructor has no variables).

Answer (score 0):

Аdd in class Animal a class field which will indicate if something goes wrong.

Or you can create a subclass EmptyAnimal which extends Animal, create and return this type, and check return value like this

```
Animal newborn = make_child(a,b);
if (newbor instanceof EmptyAnimal){
    System.out.println("something goes wrong");
}
```